# Is a decreasing and assymptotic (for y=const) convex function always logarithmically convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, economics

In short, I have a function $p(x)$ which is defined for $x\geq0$. The function is convex, decreasing and assymptotically approaches 0 for $x\rightarrow\infty$ . I need to know if $p''p\geq (p')^2$ .

As for the function, you may think that $p(x)$ is a type of investment function ($x$ is investment amount) and $p$ is the probability of some threat happening (the higher is the investment the  lower is the probability): $p'(x)<0$. And the effectiveness of investments falls with investment, so $p''(x)>0$.
If required, it is possible to assume, that the function is smooth, and $p^{(2n)}>0$ and $p^{(2n+1)}<0$ for any $n=0,1,\dots$. No need to say, that the function is convex.

After long search I came across the notion of logarithmic derivative, elasticity and log-convex functions, though I found no definitive answer, but just a list of useless (for me) definitions.

I need a mathematically rigorous proof of my assumption or... a counterexample. All suitable functions (I know only two of such kind: $\frac{a}{bx+c}$ and $ae^{-bx+c}$ or $ae^{-bx^n+c}$ ($n>1$) ) are log-convex and satisfy the required relation. Any relevant link or a scientific paper or a reference to a math book is welcome.

Comment: The answers to [this question at mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/51054/30514) mention two textbooks. The one from Boyd doesn't seem to be helpful from a quick skim around page 105. I have nominated this question for migration to math.SE, where you have a better chance of getting answers.

Comment: I see that you are asking about convexity in your question title, but don't mention it in the body of your question. That of course makes a difference for my answer... do you require that $p$ be convex? (And while we are at it, I assume you want $p$ to be twice continuously differentiable?)

Comment: To Stephan Kolassa. Yes to both questions. The main question is not precise. I will update the text to be accurate.

Comment: This should be false. We know that *completely monotonic* functions (i.e., where $(-1)^nf^{(n)}\geq 0$ for *all* $n$) are log-convex. (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/51097/30514), and an exercise *Convex functions and their applications* by Nicolescu & Persson.) You have the weaker property that this holds for $n\leq 2$. If this was sufficient for log-convexity, I assume this would be stated somewhere.

Comment: Exercise 3 in section 2.1 of the Nicolescu & Persson book (p. 70 [here](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/CUPold/np-convex.pdf), citing a 1928 paper by Montel) looks promising: $p$ is log-convex iff $x\mapsto e^{\alpha x}p(x)$ is convex for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Which after differentiating twice is equivalent to $p''(x)+2\alpha p'(x)+\alpha^2 p(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ and $\alpha$. I feel there must be a counterexample in there somewhere, struggling to get out.

Comment: It is true for a Pareto type I distribution: $\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 a b^a x^{-a-1} & x\geq b \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$, where $a>-1$ which by definition, it is.

Comment: @Carl: I don't think I quite understand what you are saying. Unless I am mistaken, the Pareto type I fulfulls the conditions, but is not a counterexample to the claim, since $$p''p-(p')^2 = (ab^a)^2\big((a+1)(a+2)-(a+1)^2\big)x^{-2a-4} \geq 0. $$ Could you elaborate?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I was not trying to find a counterexample, I was presenting another example to those in the question itself because the OP only knew of two.

Comment: @Carl: ah, good, thanks for explaining. As a matter of fact, all $x^k$ for $k<0$ fit the bill (and are completely monotonic, thus log-convex). The function is not required to be a density and integrate to one.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yup, but in a stats site densities are frequently asked for.

Answer (score 2):

> If required, it is possible to assume, that the function is smooth, and $p^{(2n)}>0$ and $p^{(2n+1)}<0$ for any $n=0,1,\dots$

If we can assume this, then $p$ is log-convex, because this is the definition for $p$ to be [*completely monotonic*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyMonotonicFunction.html). And completely monotonic functions are log-convex by exercise 6 in section 2.1 in *Convex Functions and Their Applications* by Nicolescu & Persson (p. 70 [here](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/CUPold/np-convex.pdf)). (If you need a solution for that exercise, you might get help at Math.SE.)

If we *cannot* assume this, then $p(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{arctan}(x)$ seems to be a counterexample, at least for small $x$: it fits your conditions on $p$, $p'$ and $p''$, but $p''(x)p(x)-(p'(x))^2<0$ for small $x$. [Here is the calculation and a plot.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28pi%2F2-arctan%28x%29%29+*+second+derivative+of+pi%2F2-arctan%28x%29-%28derivative+of+pi%2F2-arctan%28x%29%29%5E2)

A slightly more restricted version of your question with the original conditions (without complete monotonicity) could be whether $p''(x)p(x)\geq (p'(x))^2$ holds "eventually", i.e., for all $x>b$ for some $b$ (that depends on $p$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Looks like it is what I was looking for (completely monotonic function... that was the term I never came across). I should study the reference more thoroughly (as well as your counterexample) but seems like this is what I was looking for... for about a year. Thank you for your time, links and expertise.

Comment: +1 Appears to be good answer, only thing I lack is some strong motivation for asking the question. The only one I can think of is when log-convexity becomes important, an abstract *but not unheard of* context for discussion.

Comment: To Carl. In order to satisfy your curiosity (at least a bit), I am working on an idea of an effect of investments (economics) on self-protection (probability). I do not know what is the exact shape of the investment-to-probability function p(x), but, logically, it should be conex. Now, in the further (mathematical) research (with most of the functions not known, but only their approximate shape), I come across p'(x)/p(x) relation. I just need to know if it is growing or falling with x in order to prove the tendency (investment in self-protection rise or fall).

Comment: For those, who could be potentially interested in the topic, and find a reference to an excercise (without a solution) as not suitable, you may look for the following paper :  Milan Merkle; Completely Monotone Functions: A Digest. Published in Analytic Number Theory, Approximation Theory, and Special Functions pp 347-364, Springer. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4939-0258-3_12 . (you will need Lemma 4.2 and 4.1 as support)